# Who wins this hand

Tags: home-game

I have 5♥9♥
My mate has K♥3♣

The cards on the board are T♥ 4♥J♥6♥7⋄.

My question, who will win on the flush draw? My 2 hearts or his 1 high-card heart?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming this is No Limit Hold'em, his K♥ will beat your 9♥.

He has a K♥J♥T♥6♥4♥ flush
you have a J♥T♥9♥6♥5♥ flush

As Herb's link points out, your hand is the best 5 of the 7 cards in your hand and the board - it makes no difference whether you use 0, 1 or 2 of your hole cards.

Comment: We like color here.  Put out the winning hand in cards in color and I will give you an up vote.